# Stacking Items of a list with np.vstack in one Matrix

Tags: python

I am pretty new to Python, trying to tackle the following problem:
Imagine having the following numpy arrays (either empty or n x 2 Arrays):

```
a = np.array([])  
b = np.array([1,2])
c = np.array([[5,6],[7,8]])
d = np.array([[11,12],[13,14],[15,16]])
```

These are now put in a list E like so:

```
E = [a,b,c,d]
```

Now, I want the items to be stacked in a m x 2 Matrix, I tried using:

```
F = np.vstack(E)
```

but this gives me an error, because of the dimension problems of the empty array.
I want the Output to look like this:

```
output = [[1 2]
          [5 6]
          [7 8]
          [11 12]
          [13 14]
          [15 16]]
```

Comment: remove the ``a`` from ``E``, problem solved.

Comment: Your array ``a`` doesn't have the shape of ``n x 2``. Either fill it with ``[0,0]`` or leave it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments from @Karina, you must remove empty arrays beforehand. Sop just change how you declare E to include some sort of filter:

```
E = [i for i in (a, b, c, d) if len(i) > 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and @Karina for your comments